# RESTKit: Mapping JSON without mapping class

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

Below is the JSON response that I get back:

```
{
    "notificationId": 121,
    "activities": [
    143, 
    149]
}
```

Below is the mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"notificationId" : @"notificationId",
                                                  @"activities": @"activities"}];

 RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:@""
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodeSet];


[self.objectManager postObject:invitation path:@"/notifications" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    NSString *notificationId1 = [mappingResult.dictionary valueForKey:@"notificationId"];
    NSArray *activitesArray1 = [mappingResult.dictionary valueForKey:@"activities"];

    NSString *notificationId2 = [mappingResult.dictionary objectForKey:@"notificationId"];
    NSArray *activitesArray2 = [mappingResult.dictionary objectForKey:@"activities"];

    NSLog(@"notificaiton ID %@", notificationId1);
    NSLog(@"Activites %@", activitesArray1);

    NSLog(@"notification ID %@", notificationId2);
    NSLog(@"Activites %@", activitesArray2);

    NSLog(@"Activites Array %@", activitesArray);


    NSLog(@"mappingResult Dictionary %@", mappingResult.dictionary);


} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failusre");
}];
```

}

Log:

```
2014-04-21 19:17:51.273 App[57446:4403] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:250 POST 'http://www.domain.com/notifications' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.2371s mapping=0.0035s total=0.2446s]
2014-04-21 19:17:51.274 App[57446:60b] notification ID (null)
2014-04-21 19:17:51.274 App[57446:60b] Activites (null)
2014-04-21 19:17:51.274 App[57446:60b] notification ID (null)
2014-04-21 19:17:51.274 App[57446:60b] Activites (null)
2014-04-21 19:17:51.274 App[57446:60b] Activites Array (
)
2014-04-21 19:17:51.275 App[57446:60b] mappingResult Dictionary {
    "" =     {
        activities =         (
            143,
            149
        );
        notificationId = 121;
    };
}
```

Why are all the values Null?  How can I get the values of `notificationId` back as an NSString and `activities`in an array ?  Can this be done without creating a mapping class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your response descriptor is wrong. It should be:

```
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                        pathPattern:@"/notifications"
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
```

so that it matches the request you're sending (a POST, not a GET is the main issue).

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my response descriptor to be and now when I NSLog out mappingResutDictionary:  I get the following:      "<null>" =     {
        activities =         (
            148,
            149
        );
        notificationId = 124;
    };
}

Comment: So you have a dictionary with a key of `[NSNull null]` (because of the nil key path) which contains one object with `activities` and `notificationId` keys

Comment: how do I extract data from a key of [NSNull null] ?  I didn't that was possible.

Comment: `objectForKey:[NSNull null]`

Answer (score 1):

For some unknow reason, it looks like, there is a wrapper object in the dictionary, that has key value `@""` so first extract that and then everything else. Activities itself do look like array, so simply:

```
NSArray *activities = [[mappingResult.dictionary objectForKey:@""] objectForKey:@"activities"];
```

However that **notification** looks tricky, because it probably is a number. So if it is a consistent type, use:

```
NSNumber *notificationID = [[mappingResult.dictionary objectForKey:@""] objectForKey:@"notificationId"];
NSSring *notificationIDString = [notificationID stringValue];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think @"" is there b/c of my response descriptor keypath.  I updated the question with the response descriptor.  I even tried nil for the keypath and get the same results.

Comment: Try `NSArray *keys = [mappingResult allKeys];` and print that out. That gives you all keys in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. On my phone now. I'll try this in the AM

Comment: Have you had the chance to try? :-)

Comment: I did.  But it was still Null.  The answer by @wain worked.  Thank you for trying.